# Reading from Csv, adding headers starting at column 2, 4, and 6

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am wanting to add headers to my data being 2, 4, 6 as it just makes it much easier to manage datasets when you have consistent headers.

```
Col A   Col B    Col C  Col D   Col E  Col F
         data           data           data
         etc,,          etc,,          etc,,
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, usecols=[2, 4, 6])
df.columns = ["Sequence", "Start", "End"]
```

I have also tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv(“filename, sep='\t',
                  names = ["Sequence", "Start", "End", "Coverage"])
```

I have tried a number of different methods, but I cannot get adding headers to work.  There is no error message in this case but no output with a header.

Comment: It seems some  data dependent problem. Can you share your file with dummy data, 4-5 rows?

Comment: @jezrael I think the issue is likely because the columns start at 2, 4, 6 and headers traditionally go 1, 2, 3.  I can do but it seems to be happening with new excels.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure if understand - if use `usecols` parameter it filtered `[2,4,6]` columns. And for second it rename columns names if not exist... So what is problem?

Comment: @jezrael Using the first method, if I put my data in column 2, 4 and 6 I want header labeled Sequence, start and end above that.  There are no errors so it is hard to workout why it is not working.  I could try it in VMWARE and see if a fresh install of python helps.

Comment: Sure, but what means it does not working? Can you explain more?

Comment: @jezrael I was using a try except block.  Woops.     raise ValueError("Usecols do not match names.")
ValueError: Usecols do not match names.  Looks my suspicion was correct.  How to correct it......

Comment: Without data imposible answer...

Comment: @jezrael Here is my exact excel. http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=01037884617592945704 .  I will update the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `index_col=False` for not convert first column to index and then `usecols[1,3,5]` for select `2.,4,6.` columns, because python counts from `0`. Last add parameter names for new columns names and add `header=None` for read first row to data:

```
df = pd.read_excel('HA.xlsx', 
                   index_col=False, 
                   usecols=[1,3,5], 
                   names=["Sequence", "Start", "End"],
                   header=None)
print (df)

  Sequence      Start        End
0      awd   awdwdawd    wadwdwd
1    dawdw  wdadawdwd      wdadd
2    awawd  wadawdawd  waddwaawd
3    wadaw        NaN    dwadawd
```